# Looking for multi database data processing for spring batch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a situation where I need to call 3 databases and create a CSV.

I have created a Batch step where I could get the data from my First database.

This gives around  10000 records.

Now from each of these records I need to get the id and use it to fetch the data from other data source. I could not able to find best solution.

Any help in finding the solution is appreciated

I tried two steps for each data source but not sure how to pass the ids to next step. ( we are talking about 10000) ids.

Is it possible to connect to all 3 databases in the same step? I am new to Spring batch so not have full grasp of all the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the second call to fetch the details of each item in an item processor. This is a common pattern and is described in the [Common Batch Patterns](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders) section of the reference documentation.

Comment: So i need to have the merge the data from both the queries and write it to a CSV. so you are suggesting that we can do both queries from with in the Item Processor passing the Ids and build a Object?

Comment: Yes. The reader would "drive" the data fetching process by reading the root object. and the processor is where you enrich items as needed. And the writer writes aggregate data.